# Condition to display the last element of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I display the last element of an array without a comma?
For example, I have the following SQL query I want to execute:

SELECT name, year FROM student WHERE id = 9;

```
String[] columns = new String[] { name, year };
        String query;

        int length = columns.length;
        int max = 0;
        int i;

        if (length > 0) {

            query = "SELECT ";
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                query += columns[i] + ", ";
                max++;
                if(max <= length){
                    query += columns[i];
                }

            }
            query += " FROM " + table + " WHERE id = " + column.getId() + ";";
```

This will execute the following query: "SELECT name, year, FROM student WHERE id = 9" (The getter has a scanner in it. I'm entering the ID on the keyboard, but how can I get rid of the comma in the last element?

I have tried so far to create an IF statement to do so, but I have failed My logic makes sense, but I have no idea how to write it in code.

I want to say "if i equals to columns[max i - 1] then display the last element of the array without the comma".

Comment: Shouldn't your original incorrect code give `SELECT name, nameyear, year FROM`? That's what it looks like, since you are appending `columns[i]` twice in a single iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    query += columns[i];
    if (i<length-1)
        query += ", ";
}
```

It checks, before adding the comma, whether this is the last element of the list.

If you're using Java 8, you can now do it in a single line, much more cleanly:

```
query += String.join(", ", columns);
```

If you're not using Java 8, and if you do this a lot, you can use [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html#join%28java.lang.Object[]%29) to do it in a single line:

```
query += Joiner.on(", ").join(columns);
```

Comment: I did that too, except I put the "query += columns[i];" inside the if statement and the comma outside. Thank you very much, your code makes sense.

Comment: You don't need Google Guava for this. With **Java 8** the `String` class got a `join()` method. The appropriate call would be `query += String.join(", ", columns);`

Comment: @ifLoop Thanks, I'll mention that too. Difficult to know to what extent one can assume people are using Java 8, but should definitely have mentioned it.

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse the check, and not add a comma before the first column :

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i > 0)
        query += ", ";
    query += columns[i];
}
```

This will add a comma before each column except of the first column.

Answer (score 2):

When using **Java 8**, you can use [String#join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) for this:

```
query += String.join(", ", columns);
```

or, again with **Java 8**, you can make use of the **Stream API**:

```
query += IntStream.range(0, columns.length)
      .mapToObj(index -> columns[index])
      .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Additionally you should consider replacing your `String query` with a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
final String[] columns = new String[]{"name", "year"};
final StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

//  ...

query.append("SELECT ");
query.append(String.join(", ", columns));
query.append(" FROM ");
query.append(table);
// ...
```

You get the final result by calling `query.toString()`

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that String.join was added in Java 8, for those who aren't using it yet for whatever reason.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Did it now :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this :

```
query += columns[i];
if(i != length-1)
    query += ", ";
```

Answer (score 1):

why just not do it like that?

```
 query += columns[0];
 for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
       query += ", "+ columns[i];
 }
```

you dont use any unnessesery if statement, and it does exactly same job